# differentiability of $(x,y)\mapsto\max\{x,y\}$

Tags: derivatives, continuity, partial-derivative

At what points are the partial derivatives of the following function not defined? And how to check for the same?

$$f(x,y) = \max \{x,y\}$$

I was able to find the partial derivatives of $f$ for $x=y$ (in which case they do not exist), but I don't know how to take the limit of the partial derivative expression when $x>y$ or $x< y$ .

Comment: How did you find the partial derivatives for $x=y$ if they don't exist??

Comment: well for every $x<y$ there is a small neighborhood of $x$ where $f(x,y)=y$ and so $\partial_x f(x,y)=0$ and $\partial_y f(x,y)=1$ for $x<y$.

Comment: @JackLee I guess OP means that they proved that the partial derivative do not exist at $(x,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If it could help

we can observe that

$$\max(x,y)=\frac 12(x+y+|x-y|)$$